# Calculate the size of a table in a schema

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to find the size of a table in my schema. I've tried to find through dba_extent as follows.

```
select segment_name,sum(bytes)/(1024*1024) size from  dba_extent where segment_type='TABLE'
and segment_name = 'mytablename'
and owner ='myschemaname'
group by segment_name;
```

It gives as 2 MB, but no way it is 2MB and I've seen its size as some 800MB in the logs while i was exporting schema.It gave the same result when i query the dba_segments. Could anyone help where I gone wrong.thanks for your time.

Comment: What logs tell you that the table is bigger?  Is it possible that the table has a LOB in it which would be a different segment name?

Comment: yes it has blob, I don't  know whether its using other segment, How can i find out that

Comment: @JustinCave, it's using another segment. thank you

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/531488/266304)? Coming at it from the other side but related enough?

Answer (score -3):

Try below SQL : Hope this will help :)

```
SELECT 
tbl.NAME AS TableName,
idx.name as indexName,
prts.[Rows],
sum(a.total_pages) as TotalPages, 
sum(a.used_pages) as UsedPages, 
sum(a.data_pages) as DataPages,
(sum(a.total_pages) * 8) / 1024 as TotalSpaceMB, 
(sum(a.used_pages) * 8) / 1024 as UsedSpaceMB, 
(sum(a.data_pages) * 8) / 1024 as DataSpaceMB
FROM 
sys.tables tbl
INNER JOIN 
sys.indexes idx ON tbl.OBJECT_ID = idx.object_id
INNER JOIN 
sys.partitions prts ON idx.object_id = prts.OBJECT_ID AND idx.index_id = prts.index_id
INNER JOIN 
sys.allocation_units a ON prts.partition_id = a.container_id
WHERE 
tbl.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' AND
idx.OBJECT_ID > 255 AND 
idx.index_id <= 1
GROUP BY 
tbl.NAME, idx.object_id, idx.index_id, idx.name, prts.[Rows]
ORDER BY 
object_name(idx.object_id)
```

Comment: Above SQL working fine for me in SQL-2008, are you trying in which DB ?

Comment: oracle doesn't have allocation_units table, i am getting table doesnt exist error and im using 10g

Comment: Ohh okay. Above SQL works for only MS-SQL Server. Wont work for Oracle.

Comment: The question is tagged as [tag:oracle].

Comment: Try :  select segment_name,segment_type,bytes/1024/1024 MB
 from dba_segments
 where segment_type='TABLE' and segment_name='<yourtablename>';